# Manga about a boy who comes back as a ghost to make up with his girlfriend

Tags: story-identification, manga

In this manga, there is one boy who dies in an accident and comes back as ghost to "haunt" the other boy he met. The boy who died then makes him go and make up with his girlfriend in his place.

He will tell her that her dead boyfriend sent him but she won't believe him. He will take her to some places and give her some gifts (there was some specific number of gifts he had to give her) and she will believe him in the end.

Answer (score 2):

[Hikaru ga Chikyuu ni Ita Koro......](https://myanimelist.net/manga/26201/Hikaru_ga_Chikyuu_ni_Ita_Koro) (2011-2014).

[image: Cover of *Hikaru ga Chikyuu ni Ita Koro......*]

> High school student Koremitsu Akagi finds himself attending the funeral of Hikaru Mikado, who had died in an accident during Golden Week. He's not sure why he's there, as he only exchanged a few words with Hikaru at school.
>
> However, Hikaru doesn't seem to be completely gone from the world, as he comes back as a ghost in order to fulfill a promise to Aoi Saotome, his fiancée. Since Koremitsu is the only one who can see him, he asks him to carry out his promise in his place.
>
> Complying with his request, Koremitsu tries to fulfill Hikaru's promises to the rest of his "girlfriends," helping them overcome past misunderstandings and repair broken relationships. But the situation surrounding Hikaru's death is shrouded in mystery, as it's uncertain whether or not he truly died in an accident...

I found Jenayah's query on a similar question at [Manga: male student dies, comes back as a ghost only seen by his female friend, they hunt for other ghosts and uncover a hoax](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/207094/manga-male-student-dies-comes-back-as-a-ghost-only-seen-by-his-female-friend) and borrowed their search string. `ghost boyfriend "only * can see" girlfriend site:myanimelist.net/manga` worked for me.

Comment: If this is correct, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.